# Determine when Safari Reader is not available

Tags: safari, shortcuts-app

The "[Get Article using Safari Reader](https://matthewcassinelli.com/actions/get-article-using-safari-reader/)" action often works quite well. It even grabs relevant images.

However, sometimes there's no article to get, and then it works poorly. For instance: https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/grocery-bag-environmental-impact. In Safari, the Show Reader command is dimmed. It's not available. But Shortcuts still tries to get the Reader view, and ends up getting basically nothing, just the footer.

Is there any way to tell when the Reader article isn't available, so I can capture via "[Get Details of Safari Web Page](https://matthewcassinelli.com/actions/get-details-of-safari-web-page/)" instead?